# short hand array if statement

Tags: javascript, arrays, if-statement

Hello I am pretty new to javascript and I am wondering how I could make my code shorter
I have an array with multiple items in it and I want to check a few things for each item i can do this with a lot of if statements but i am wondering if there's a "shorthand" way of doing it?

so is it possible to check all items in my array `deaths` and see which ones have `GetComponent('HealthComponent')._alive == 0 ?`

```
var deaths = [];

 if (deaths[0].GetComponent('HealthComponent')._alive == 0) 
     {
this.GetComponent('HealthComponent')._alive = 1;
 this.GetComponent('HealthComponent')._health = 0;
  this.Broadcast({
        topic: 'health.update',
        health: 0,
        maxHealth: 150,
      }); 
      var selected = this;
  setTimeout(function(){
             
                  
            selected.GetComponent('HealthComponent')._health = 150;
             selected.Broadcast({
        topic: 'health.update',
        health: 150,
        maxHealth: 150,
      }); 
      
         
          },60000);
     
         }

 if (deaths[1].GetComponent('HealthComponent')._alive == 0) 
     {
this.GetComponent('HealthComponent')._alive = 1;
 this.GetComponent('HealthComponent')._health = 0;
  this.Broadcast({
        topic: 'health.update',
        health: 0,
        maxHealth: 150,
      }); 
      var selected = this;
  setTimeout(function(){
             
                  
            selected.GetComponent('HealthComponent')._health = 150;
             selected.Broadcast({
        topic: 'health.update',
        health: 150,
        maxHealth: 150,
      }); 
      
         
          },60000);
     
         }
```

thanks in advance

Comment: Am I to understand that the code within each if block is exactly the same? If so you can use `Array#filter` to find items that meet the condition and then run your block of code for all of them.

Comment: @PeterKA yes each is the same within the if statement

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a for loop, for example:

```js
for (let i = 0; i < deaths.length; i++) {
  if (deaths[i].GetComponent('HealthComponent')._alive == 0) {
   // do your stuff...
  }
}
```

or you can use `forEach()` built-in method of Array, same thing but a little more declarative:

```js
death.forEach(death => {
  if (death.GetComponent('HealthComponent')._alive == 0) {
   // do your stuff...
  }
})
```

Some docs for you:

[About loops in JS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Loops_and_iteration)

[About Array.forEach](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach)

Comment: thank you for your reply which one would you suggest?

Comment: `forEach` is better - it is shorter, less code, less chance to make an mistake

Comment: 99% of the time I use `forEach()` because it is easier to read and easier to write.
But sometimes when I need to stop the loop manually (by some condition) I use common for-loop, because it supports `break`, `continue` keywords (and forEach() dont).

Also sometimes when you got a huge array of elements, and you do some operations on them, like `filter` then `map` then `reduce` then ...  . It can be better (for performance reasons) to rewrite it with for-loop, to do everything in one take (iteration), and don't go through array of 2000 elements 3 times.